# Emacs mode similar to vi's normal mode

Tags: emacs

I'm looking for an emacs mode that allows me to use M- and C- prefixed keybindings without actually typing the M and C keys. This mode would be very similar to 'normal mode' in vim or vi.

I believe I have seen some thing like this recently but I haven't managed to find it again. I think the one I recall used the comma key as a prefix somehow. Does anyone know a mode like this?

Comment: Not thinking of [viper-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViperMode) or [evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil)?

Comment: Not quite, I don't want any vi emulation. I'm looking for a way to more easily enter prefix keys (without ctrl).

Comment: god-mode sounds like it fits your description much better, but [key chords](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyChord) can also be helpful for this. (I use them with a comma prefix key.) Also, [View mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViewMode) puts you into a read-only buffer where a handful of non-editing commands are available as single keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds to me you're looking for [god-mode](https://github.com/chrisdone/god-mode). It's a minor mode for entering Emacs commands without modifier keys